Why using Tk() instead of Toplevel() for my 2nd window in Tkinter doesn't let me update a text variable in a label
I want to use Tk() for my new window, because I'm going to destroy the main one and let the second one run; however, when I use it, it doesn't let my label's textvariable updates, but with a simple change like using Toplevel() it works.
here is my code:

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def fill(s,c):
    c += 1
    the_bar['value'] = c
    if c == 25:
        text.set('text 2')
    elif c == 50:
        text.set('text 3')
    elif c == 75:
        text.set('text 4')
    if c<=s:
        loading_window.after(50,fill,s,c)
    else:
        the_bar.destroy()
        loading_window.destroy()

def load():
    global loading_window
    loading_window = Tk()
    loading_window.title('loading')
    global text
    text = StringVar()
    text.set('text 1')
    txt = Label(loading_window,textvariable=text)
    txt.pack()
    global the_bar 
    the_bar = ttk.Progressbar(loading_window,length=300,orient=HORIZONTAL,maximum=100)
    the_bar.pack()
    delay, steps, count = 50,100,0
    loading_window.after(delay,fill,steps,count)
    loading_window.mainloop()
    
load() #this is within a button in my main Tk() window


If you destroy the first window before creating the new window, then it should not have such issue.  Or you can specify the master of the textvariable when creating it.

You shouldn't create multiple instances of Tk(), this explains why.
Basically the tk.StringVar that you create is bound to the first instance of Tk() and it's not accessible from the other window.
If you want to hide the root window you can call root.withdraw() and use toplevel() for the other window.

The tk.StringVar is bound to the first Tk is true unless you pass in something for the master argument.

Like the answer above, you shouldn't use multiple separate Tk() windows. But if you insist, have you tried mainlooping your second window?
Example:
window1 = Tk()
window2 = Tk()

window1.mainloop()
window2.mainloop()


Clarification: If you don't mainloop your two windows, then Tkinter doesn't update because it isn't in a loop.

You don't need (or should not) execute mainloop() more than once.  Also your suggestion does not address OP issue.

But if there is multiple tkinter Tk() instances, mainloop() is needed to activate all the window variables

No, you don't need multiple mainloop() for multiple instances of Tk().  What you need is to specify the instance of Tk() as the master of the variable.
